# How can I get rid of t.test's "not enough x observation" error? Matrix data comparison

Tags: for-loop, matrix, t-test

I am working with a data matrix that has 86 rows(that are 86 leaves of plants) and 10 columns (that are secondary metabolites measured on 3 different points of the given leaf : proximal, middle, distal part,  + the leaf column).

I have to do a t.test on every single leaf compared to every single other leaf. The tricky part is that I have to do a t.test comparing the proximal data with the other proximal measurement data as well. So: first leaf proximal value - second leaf proximal value and this goes on for every middle and distal part as well. 
I cannot wrap around my head as to how I should write a loop for it that does this function.

```
wide <- readxl::read_xlsx("dualbeat.xlsx")
head(wide)

tmp <-as.data.frame(wide)

ttt<- tmp$aluchl[1]
tt2<- tmp$aluchl[2]

t.test(ttt,tt2, mu = 0, alt= "two.sided", conf = 0.90, var.equal = FALSE, paired = F)
help(t.test)
```

I wish to have all the measurements t.tested and the the t.test command gives the return "not enough x observations"